# asp.net mvc cannot load another action before one action completed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wanna define a class "SessionContext" to trace every guest's specific actions.The class defined as below:

```
public class SessionContext
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my controllers,I have a base controller,and every controller inherit fome it. The code as below:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private static Dictionary<string, SessionContext> _sessionDic 
        = new Dictionary<string, SessionContext>();

    public static Dictionary<string, SessionContext> SessionDic
    {
        get { return _sessionDic; }
        set { _sessionDic = value; }
    }
}
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
        return View();
    }
}
```

In my Global.asax,I add two event:

```
 protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, SessionContext> sessionDic = BaseController.SessionDic;
        string sessionId = Session.SessionID;
        if (!sessionDic.Keys.Contains(sessionId.Trim()))
        {
            sessionDic.Add(sessionId, new SessionContext());
        }
    }
    protected void Session_OnEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, SessionContext> sessionDic = BaseController.SessionDic;
        string sessionId = Session.SessionID;
        if (sessionDic.Keys.Contains(sessionId))
        {
            sessionDic.Remove(sessionId);
        }
    }
```

That's all my code. The problem which I met is:
when I open a tab in my browser and access Home/Test,it'll wait for 30s by my intention.
but during the 30s,I cannot to access other actions(/Home/Index for example). I cannot figure it out,can anyone tell me why this scenario happens?

Comment: I think your asking the current thread which handles the whole web application to sleep when you call ( System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);) , instead why don't you handle this delay in loading in JavaScript its easier and safer!!

Comment: It's just a sample,in my real project,I will do a job which required lots of time in Test action,and during the time I cann't open any new pages. The reason I just found is the event Session_Start,if I remove it,the web application works well.But if I add this event in gloabal.asax even I do nothing in it ,the problem still exist.